# Firebase query return wrong value

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

when I use OrderByChild or key with startAt or equalTo it returns wrong value

This is with equalTo

```java
        String diy = intent.getStringExtra(PARCELABLE_KEY);
        Query qr = dr.child(AddDIYFragment.DIY_CHILD).orderByChild("title").equalTo(diy);
```

This is with startAt

```java
        Query searchQueryNum2 = reference.child(AddDIYFragment.DIY_CHILD).orderByChild("title").startAt(text);
        searchQueryNum2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(this);
```

I try orderByKey but it also doesnt work

EDIT JSON TREE EXAMPLE(EDited but I cand add more)

```
{
  "gg0" : {
    "category" : "lifestyle",
    "eq" : "SMTH",
    "title" : "gg"
  },
  "hdhshs5" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "hshsj",
    "title" : "hdhshs"
  },
  "hdhshsjsjs6" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "eooe",
    "title" : "hdhshsjsjs"
  },
  "java1" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "hshjs",
    "title" : "java"
  },
  "jshsjs7" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "hdhshsjjs",
    "title" : "jshsjs"
  },
  "jsjsjsjs9" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "hshshwhw",
    "title" : "jsjsjsjs"
  },
  "papajs8" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "hdhshhajasjjs",
    "title" : "papajs"
  },
  "sjs4" : {
    "category" : "Sports",
    "eq" : "hdhs",
    "title" : "sjs"
  }
}
```

EDIT onDataChange:-

this is a simple startAt

```java
        Query searchQueryNum2 = reference.child(AddDIYFragment.DIY_CHILD).orderByChild("title").startAt("gg");
        Log.d(TAG, "query is made");
        searchQueryNum2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(this);
```

And onDataChange

```java
    private ArrayList<Prod> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot temp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            list.add(temp.getValue(Prod.class));
            Log.d(TAG, "list added something " + list.get(list.size() - 1));

        }
}
```

EDIT 
I set the child to be orderd by startat "gg" and as you see in the top we have gg but it return also (hdhshs,java,jsjsjsjs,papajs ,sjs, etc)

Comment: What do you mean through "returns wrong value"? What is the expected value? Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks and I added the JSON tree example

Comment: What do you mean through "returns wrong value"? What is the expected value?

Comment: @AlexMamo I mean when I want a specific title to search for it doesn't return it returns the wrong one like if you type `reference.child(AddDIYFragment.DIY_CHILD).orderByChild("title").startAt(text);`
it returns null or not the object you want

Comment: Show us a concrete example without using variables. Use hardcoded values.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the onDataChange and use of startAt()

Comment: What do the logs in that new code output? What did you expect them to output? And what value of `text` did you test with?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks a lot for the reply...I expect it returns the gg0 node in the JSON tree example above but it returns a lot more (nodes I didn't write in the JSON tree example because it is much more)
I mean it returns what I want and more things I don't want and it doesn't match the Query and in other times it doesn't return what I want only what I don't want and returned snapshot doesn't match the Query I typed

Comment: Can you give: 1) an example of a node that is being returned that you want? 2) an example of a node that is being returned that you don't want? 3) the value of `text` that you use for searching?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry sir for the late reply I add what you want the query and the result with the JSON tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
...orderByChild("title").startAt("gg")
```

This is executed by Firebase in the following way:

1. Order all children of the reference by their title.
2. Find the child whose title start with `gg`, or the first one after that if no child starts with `gg`.
3. Start returning results from there, until we run out of results.

I think you're looking for a `startsWith(...)` operator, which Firebase doesn't natively have, but can easily be created by combining `startAt()` and `endAt()`.

```
...orderByChild("title").startAt("gg").endAt("gg\uf8ff")
```

With this, you're adding an extra step to the recipe above:

4. Stop returning results once we reach a title that is greater than `gg\uf8ff`.